# How do I combine two axis of 1-D noise into contigious 2-D noise?

Tags: c, 2d, noise-generator

Firstly, I am new to asking questions here (although I have lurked about for quite a while) so please excuse me if I don't format or word things correctly.
Secondly, I'm *not* looking for links to any libraries (personally, I don't like them because I don't have access to the source... and, *in my opinion*, they feel like a potential security exploit waiting to happen), I'm just after plain old C code to do the desired task (preferably not using objects/structs).

---

I am trying to generate 2-dimensional noise, and I seem to have hit a roadblock.

I have written my own pseudorandom number generator, where you give it seed/input values and it always gives the same output (from 0.0 -> 1.0) for the same seed/input. In other words, it can happily generate deterministic 1-dimensional noise.
Using this method, I can create seperate x/y axis of noise (I would post example images to demonstrate what I mean, but I require 10 rep points to post images... but suffice it to say that they look like black/grey/white barcodes oriented horizontally/vertically)
However my efforts to combine to two axis have resulted in an image that resembles a black & white "tartan" type of pattern (again, I'd post demo images if I could). I'm after a "fluffy cloud" style pattern, like perlin noise generates.

My goal is to have a single function that when supplied seed/x/y values it gives the desired 2-D output.

Precomputing an array of values (which is the method I've found in several places on Google) is out of the question here. The noise is to be used for procedural world generation, and the 2-D input co-ordinates can go from -1,088,391,168 to +1,088,391,168 (for both x & y axis, which would be (4*(10^18)) bytes)... so the output has to depend directly on the input values given and calculated on-the-fly.

---

My question is: given two seperate axis of 1-D noise (x axis/y axis) how can I combine the two axis into a single 2-D noise value? Or in other words, how can I combine my horizontal and vertical barcodes together to create a 2-D noise field?

---

EDIT:

```
const double noise_x1 = Noise(seed, x);
const double noise_x2 = Noise(seed, x + 1);

const double noise_y1 = Noise(seed + 1, y);
const double noise_y2 = Noise(seed + 1, y + 1);
```

This gets the noise values for the x/y axis, and the noise values for the next x/y point. How can I mathematically combine these 4 values for use as the "corners" of the "grid cell"? Do I simply average them out?
EG:

```
const double noise_x1y1 = (noise_x1 + noise_y1) * 0.5;
const double noise_x2y1 = (noise_x2 + noise_y1) * 0.5;
const double noise_x1y2 = (noise_x1 + noise_y2) * 0.5;
const double noise_x2y2 = (noise_x2 + noise_y2) * 0.5;
```

And then what would the formula/algorithm be for interpolating the exact spot inside the given "cell"?
I've seen other people use "grid based logic" for noise but it seems to befuddle me :P

---

UPDATE (7:35pm, 30th October 2014, Australian Eastern Standard Time/AEST):

Upon digging even further into this problem, I've come across Morton codes (which aren't actually related to noise functions, although they can be used to "hash" the input co-ordinates into a single number). Morton codes interleave the bits of two input numbers like so:
First input number...

```
00000001 -> 00000000 00000001 = 1  
00000010 -> 00000000 00000100 = 4  
00000100 -> 00000000 00010000 = 16  
00001000 -> 00000000 01000000 = 64  
00010000 -> 00000001 00000000 = 256  
00100000 -> 00000100 00000000 = 1024  
01000000 -> 00010000 00000000 = 4096  
10000000 -> 01000000 00000000 = 16384
```

Second input number...

```
00000001 -> 00000000 00000010 = 2  
00000010 -> 00000000 00001000 = 8  
00000100 -> 00000000 00100000 = 32  
00001000 -> 00000000 10000000 = 128  
00010000 -> 00000010 00000000 = 512  
00100000 -> 00001000 00000000 = 2048  
01000000 -> 00100000 00000000 = 8192  
10000000 -> 10000000 00000000 = 32768
```

These two output numbers are then combined together into a single number. This process can be easily expanded out to work with two 32bit inputs (to form a single 64bit output).

The output number can then be fed into a 1-Dimensional noise function, giving deterministic output for any 32bit inputs.

Comment: Ok, if I get what you are saying, what you are calling 1-axis noise is your randomly generated number that represents the amplitude of noise in the horizontal. You say you have another similar axis representing noise in the vertical. You say you want to combine them into the normal `fluffy cloud` representation of noise instead of a `tartan pattern`. I think I get it. The issue is noise/sound is generally a frequency (amplitude over cycles per second). To get a fluffy cloud, why not scale your vertical `amplitude` from '0' to its max back to '0' over the horiz-axis period of time?

Comment: If you want something that looks like Perlin noise, the easiest approach is to write a Perlin noise generator.

Comment: By the way, it's not clear how you're "combining" your 1D data. You're aware that you need N^2 independent points for 2D, whereas two 1D sets only gives you 2N?

Comment: The "tartan pattern" the I described (I'm fairly certain) is being caused by incorrectly interpolating the 2 axis, resulting in the center of each "grid cell" (if you think of the entire image as a X*Y grid) rounding incorrectly.
I'll see if I can add some code to the question to clarify...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to get true, deterministic xD noise is to use some hash function to combine the coordinates together:

1. Convert the coordinates into integers of the desired granularity.
2. Hash the integers together. Your requirement is somewhere between a simple function that is used for hash tables and the overkill produced by cryptographic hashes. Where you strike the compromise is entirely up to you, so I can't give too much advise on which hash function to use.
3. Convert the resulting hash into a float between 0 and 1.

Comment: I agree that hashing the two co-ordinates together into a single number and then feeding that number into my 1-D noise function seems to be in the right direction. Since posting the OP, I've been looking into Morton codes, which seems to be the way to go. Thank you very much for the answer, I would upvote this if I could.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this: https://gist.github.com/KdotJPG/b1270127455a94ac5d19

2D, 3D, and 4D noise with significantly fewer directional artifacts than Perlin noise, and especially compared to what you're attempting to do.

Comment: Thank you for the input, I would upvote if I could.

However, your solution seems to be a bit "heavy duty" (overkill) for my purposes... the end result would be what I'm after, but the computational requirements would be alot higher than I'm after.

Thank you again.

Comment: The computational requirements are not much different than those of Perlin noise. There's just a lot of code because things are expanded. That's intended to /improve/ performance. For example, the 0,0,0 and 1,1,1 tetrahedra in the 3D implemetation could be handled by the same code. That would make the filesize smaller, but would not necessarily improve performance. And if 2D is all you need, notice that the 2D function isn't very big anyway. You can outright delete the code for 3D and 4D if you don't need it.

Comment: I understand that it's not that much different to Perlin noise. But, I was after results that resembled Perlin noise, without the computational requirements. This is why I've been trying to combine the two 1-D computations... it's waaay simpler, and it's substantially faster because of this. The implementation I've been working on is going to leave Perlin in the dust (performance wise). Looking at your code, it seems to resemble the 4-D algorithms to achieve 2-D tileable noise, and that's what Google showed me in the first place.

Comment: BTW... After looking over your code again, IMO I feel that you could see potential performance gains by converting vars that are only calculated on initialization into constant vars (for instance, the <stretchOffset> vars). I've personally seen the effect that can have on an algorithm/function. From my experiences, I've seen up to 25% throughput gains simply from converting vars that don't need to be written again into contants. The more _reads_ that a var has, the more substantial the gains (however single reads potentially have a negative effect, so it's not _always_ the way to go)...

Comment: I'm assuming that's what the "final" qualifier does (haven't done java coding myself)?